# Count function for the last columns

Tags: sas

How do i stat a count function for the last 3 columns in my dataset, putting into consideration that the name of the last 3 columns always changes

```
Data test;
Set test1;
Count=count(coulmn12,column13,column14);
Run;
```

Comment: `COUNT(string, substring <, modifier(s)>) ` is a string function! What are you counting ? The number of non-missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query a data set's metadata to get the names of the last three columns.

```
data have;
  retain id x1-x15 z1-z12 . ;
  id+1; z10 = 1; output;
  id+1; z11 = 3.14159; output;
  id+1; z12 = 42; output;
  format _numeric_ 4.;
run;

* get data sets metadata;
proc contents noprint data=have out=have_metadata;
run;

* query for names of last 3 columns;
proc sql noprint;
  select name 
  into :last_three_columns separated by ','
  from have_metadata 
  having varnum > max(varnum) - 3
  ;

%put NOTE: &=last_three_columns;

data want;
  attrib last3_nmiss_count length=8;
  set have;
  last3_nmiss_count = nmiss(&last_three_columns);
run;

dm 'viewtable
 want(keep=last3_nmiss_count id z:)';
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you make a comma delimited list of variables but then add the OF keyword in the function call?  That will just pass the first name to the OF keyword and the other two as normal comma delimited arguments.  Either use a space delimited list and the OF keyword or else just remove the OF keyword.

Comment: left over coding artifact (fixed, removed `OF`). Technically not incorrect, but inconsistent to the eagle eyed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an ARRAY.  And the old if 0 then set.

```
data have;
   retain id x1-x5 z1-z6 . z7-z10 . a ' ' z11-z12 . ;
   id+1; z10 = 1; output;
   id+1; z11 = 3.14159; output;
   id+1; z12 = 42; output;
   format _numeric_ 4.;
   run;
data want;
   if 0 then set have(drop=id /*or other numeric vars as needed*/);
   array _v[*] _numeric_;
   set have;
   nmiss_3 = nmiss(_v[dim(_v)],_v[dim(_v)-1],_v[dim(_v)-2]);
   run;
data want; /*move ID and NMISS_3 back to left*/
   if 0 then set want(keep=id nmiss_3);
   set want;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]